# Use an es module package in a commonjs project?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use an es module package with a commonjs project. I'm getting the error

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/user/Documents/git/test/node_modules/logger/lib/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/user/Documents/git/test/node_modules/logger/lib/index.js from /Users/user/Documents/git/test/testLogger.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/user/Documents/git/test/node_modules/logger/package.json.
```

The package in question is actually my own package. What can I do to make it work with commonjs (other than replacing all the imports)?

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: @Sehdev v13.10.1

Comment: As your error suggest try removing 1type:module` from `package.json ` file.

Comment: @Sehdev the npm package needs type module, the local project needs type commonjs. I can't remove either

Answer (score -1):

You need install `babel-register` and `babel-preset-env`

```js
// add to index.js or start.js
require('babel-register')({
  presets: ['env']
});
```

See more here https://appdividend.com/2019/01/23/javascript-import-statement-tutorial-with-example/